# Return image asynchronously

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have image in Image object and wants to display the image on the screen using jQuery asynchronous request.

Please give me some solution.

Thanks

Munish

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an asynchronous call for this. A simple controller action returning the image:

```
public ActionResult Image()
{
    byte[] imageData  = ...
    return File(imageData, "image/jpeg");
}
```

and then inject an `<img>` tag pointing to this controller action into the DOM:

```
$('#someButton').click(function() {
    // when some button is clicked show the image:
    var imageUrl = '<%= Url.Action("Image", "SomeController") %>';
    $('body').append(
        $('<img/>').attr('src', imageUrl).attr('alt', '')
    );
});
```

which will perform an async request and show the image.

Comment: small edit: var imageUrl = 'Url.Action("Image", "SomeController")'; to var imageUrl = '<%: Url.Action("Image", "SomeController")' %>;